# Passing NSData Content To MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my application I'm using Files(.mp4) which are in encrypted format. These files are stored in the Documents Folder in my Application Sandbox. I've Decrypted these MP4 files & the resultant Decrypted bytes are stored in an NSDATA obj. I wish to pass this NSData to MPMoviePlayerController without writing the NSDATA to a file. How do i go about achieving this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to avoid that if you want to use MPMoviePlayerController to play the movie.

Comment: Right, there's no initializer for MPMoviePlayerController with NSData, so you gotta write it before using.

Comment: @onnoweb Is there any default IOS MediaPlayer which supports NSData.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. It seems you'll need to write your decrypted video to disk first and then load via a file URL.

Comment: @How do i go about writing a customized Video Player?